# Реализация getchar на голом C

Tags: c, io, ос

**Здрасте!** Уж не знаю, что на меня нашло, но захотелось попробовать своими руками создать маленькую ОС. За основу для ядра был выбран C. Но возникла следующая проблема: как реализовать ввод (а для начала хотя бы аналог getchar), не имея библиотек?
Думаю мой вопрос довольно сложный и бесполезный, но надеюсь получу на него ответ)
Если что, следовал я гайду на [osdev.org](http://osdev.org).

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если пользоваться этим гайдом, то в самом низу будет [read_serial()](https://wiki.osdev.org/Serial_Ports).

К нему надо привинтить текущую дисциплину терминала (echo, translate CR/NL редактирование ввода (в смысле обработки Backspace и т.п.) и буфер, куда он будет класть входящие символы.
Сам `getchar()` будет брать символы из этого буфера.

Вообще, вам надо принять принципиальное решение, вы в своей ОС работаете по прерываниям (тогда `read_serial()` надо связать с IRQ обработчиком) или синхронно. Если синхронно, то `getchar()` должен сам вызывать `read_serial()` если в буфере нет даных.

Вызываемый `read_serial()` выберет из девайса и положит в буфер сколько сможет символов, скажем, учитывая таймаут вычисляемый по текущей скорости девайса.

Ну, `read_serial()` стоит несколько обобщить, например, передавать ей базовый адрес блока регистров девайса и м.б. какое-то его описание. Тогда одной программой можно читать несклько разных устройств.

В общем, что-то в таком духе.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь неплохо описано как это делается.
https://subscribe.ru/archive/comp.soft.myosdev/201207/24185612.html